# I want to compare the distinct values from column a with values mentioned in IN condition , and print true if all the values match with in condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
if ((select distinct Column_A from TableA) == ('ab','bc','dc','ec'))
    print 'True'
else
    print 'False'
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select convert(bit,
       case 
       when (select count(distinct column_A) from TableA
             where column_A in ('ab','bc','dc','ec')
            ) = 4
       then 1
       else 0
       end
       ) tf
```

[online demo](http://rextester.com/ATKO75501)

Comment: the values should match and not the count

Comment: ummm, for the count to be 4 each each of those 4 values must be in the data, give it some more thought. If 'ab' was missing then the count would be 3. if only 'dc' & 'ec' exist in the data the count = 2. **ONLY when ALL 4 exist in the data** will the `count(distinct column_A)` = 4

Comment: Go to the online demo. change the data so that at least one of those values is missing, run it. what happens?